# @ManyToMany - composite PK - Exception: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, composite-primary-key

I am getting an exception like this...

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.mysite.model.SellerProduct from com.mysite.model.Product has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

I am working on a web application, where scenario is: ***A product can be sell by many sellers.***

I am trying to achieve: **If i load product object, all sellers who sell that product must come with product object.**

Table structure:

```
create table product(
    productid int(12) not null AUTO INCREMENT,
    // other attributes
    PRIMARY KEY(productid)
);

create table seller(
    SellerID int(12) not null AUTO INCREMENT,
    // other attributes
    PRIMARY KEY(SellerID)
);

create table seller_product(
    SellerID int(12) not null AUTO INCREMENT,
    productid int(12) not null AUTO INCREMENT,
    // other attributes
    PRIMARY KEY(SellerID,productid),
    key `productid_fk` (`productid`),
    constraint `productid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`productid`) REFERENCES `product` (`productid`),
    constraint `sellerid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`sellerid`) REFERENCES `seller` (`SellerID`)
);
```

Java Code looks like this:

Product.java

```
package com.mysite.model;

// all import statements

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="productid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "SELLER_PRODUCT", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "productid")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="sellerid") })
    private Set<SellerProduct> seller;

    public Set<SellerProduct> getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }

    public void setSeller(Set<SellerProduct> seller) {
        this.seller = seller;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    // other variables and getter-setters
}
```

Seller.java

```
package com.mysite.model;

// all import packages

@Entity
@Table(name="SELLER")
public class Seller {

    @Id
    @Column(name="SellerID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int sellerId;

    @ManyToMany (mappedBy="seller")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

    public int getSellerId() {
        return sellerId;
    }

    public void setSellerId(int sellerId) {
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    // other variables and getter-setters

}
```

SellerProduct.java

```
package com.mysite.model;

// all import packages 

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class SellerProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    SellerProductId sellerProductId;

    public SellerProductId getSellerProductId() {
        return sellerProductId;
    }

    public void setSellerProductId(SellerProductId sellerProductId) {
        this.sellerProductId = sellerProductId;
    }

    // other variables and getter setters
}
```

SellerProductId.java

```
package com.mysite.model;

// all import packages

@Embeddable
public class SellerProductId { 
    @Column(name="productId")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name="sellerId")
    private int sellerId;

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public int getSellerId() {
        return sellerId;
    }

    public void setSellerId(int sellerId) {
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
    }    
}
```

Am I wrong in some mapping?? (I tried to search on google but can not get success!)

Can anyone please help????

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution.
Hint, I got from [First Link](http://java-aap.blogspot.in/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html) and [Second Link](http://java-aap.blogspot.in/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html)

Actually, I am trying to implement many to many relationship in bidirectional with some addition columns in intermediate table.
And the problem is in my mapping.
I did mapping exact like as suggested in [First Link](http://java-aap.blogspot.in/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html) links.